# getting the median of the data from k means clustering

Tags: r

Suppose we have the following code I need to get the median instead of the mean

```
USArrests %>%
  mutate(Cluster = final$cluster) %>%
  group_by(Cluster) %>%
  summarise_all("mean")
```

When I replace the word it gives an error

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `summarise_all("mean")` with `summarise_all("median")` should work. Moreover, `summarise_all` has been deprecated, you can use `across` :

```
library(dplyr)

USArrests %>%
  mutate(Cluster = final$cluster) %>%
  group_by(Cluster) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = median))
```